# Make shared property reactive in Vue Composition API composable by declaring variable outside of exported function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api, composable

I am using the composition api plugin for vue2 (https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api) to reuse composables in my app.

I have two components that reuse my `modalTrigger.js` composable, where I'd like to declare some sort of shared state (instead of using a bloated vuex state management).

So in my components I do something like:

```
import modalTrigger from '../../../../composables/modalTrigger';

export default {
    name: 'SearchButton',
    setup(props, context) {
        const { getModalOpenState, setModalOpenState } = modalTrigger();


        return {
            getModalOpenState,
            setModalOpenState,
        };
    },
};
```

And in my modalTrigger I have code like:

```
import { computed, ref, onMounted } from '@vue/composition-api';

let modalOpen = false; // needs to be outside to be accessed from multiple components

export default function () {
    modalOpen = ref(false);
    const getModalOpenState = computed(() => modalOpen.value);

    const setModalOpenState = (state) => {
        console.log('changing state from: ', modalOpen.value, ' to: ', state);
        modalOpen.value = state;
    };

    onMounted(() => {
        console.log('init trigger');
    });

    return {
        getModalOpenState,
        setModalOpenState,
    };
}
```

This works, but only because I declare the `modalOpen` variable outside of the function.
If I use this:

```
export default function () {
    const modalOpen = ref(false); // <------
    const getModalOpenState = computed(() => modalOpen.value);
    ...
```

It is not reactive because the modalTrigger is instantiated twice, both with it's own reactive property.

I don't know if that is really the way to go, it seems, that I am doing something wrong.

I also tried declaring the ref outside:

```
const modalOpen = ref(false);

export default function () {
    const getModalOpenState = computed(() => modalOpen.value);
```

But this would throw an error:

> Uncaught Error: [vue-composition-api] must call Vue.use(plugin) before using any function.

So what would be the correct way to achieve this?
I somehow expected Vue to be aware of the existing modalTrigger instance and handling duplicate variable creation itself...

Well, anyway, thanks a lot in advance for any hints and tipps.

Cheers

### Edit:

The complete header.vue file:

```
<template>
    <header ref="rootElement" :class="rootClasses">
        <button @click="setModalOpenState(true)">SET TRUE</button>
        <slot />
    </header>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, computed } from '@vue/composition-api';
import subNavigation from '../../../../composables/subNavigation';
import mobileNavigation from '../../../../composables/mobileNavigation';
import search from '../../../../composables/searchButton';
import { stickyNavigation } from '../../../../composables/stickyNav';
import metaNavigation from '../../../../composables/metaNavigation';
import modalTrigger from '../../../../composables/modalTrigger';


export default {
    name: 'Header',
    setup(props, context) {
        const { rootElement, rootClasses } = stickyNavigation(props, context);

        mobileNavigation();
        subNavigation();
        search();
        metaNavigation();
        const { getModalOpenState, setModalOpenState } = modalTrigger();

        onMounted(() => {
            console.log('Header: getModalOpenState: ', getModalOpenState.value);
            setModalOpenState(true);
            console.log('Header: getModalOpenStat: ', getModalOpenState.value);
        });

        return {
            rootClasses,
            rootElement,
            getModalOpenState,
            setModalOpenState,
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

The composition API is setup somewhere else where there are Vue components mounted a bit differently than you normally would.

So I can't really share the whole code,but it has this inside:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import CompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api';

Vue.use(CompositionApi)
```

The composition API and every other composable works just fine...

Comment: please share the main.js file

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I added a bit more information.